# How to extract separated observation spaces from Vectorized Environments in gymnasium

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

How can we separate observation space of multiple environment returned by env.reset or env.step functions for Vectorized Environments?

Or is there a way to get individual environment from Vectorized Environments like env.envs[i], where i in range[0,n] where n is the number of environments in env.

Thank you. Any hint will be appreciated.

flatten(env.single_observation_space ,s) will get the observation space of first element, but I am not able to get the observation spaces of the rest of the envs.